# Why the client redirected to "/" instead of the given url in the response?

Tags: http

I'm trying to try making a login form but I went to problem. The client should be redirect to "/home" but instead it go to "/". Did I do something wrong?

**Http Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /home
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me. If the response says `Location: /home` and the client then requests `/` instead of `/home`, the client is faulty.

Comment: you right. I try changed my browser from Firefox Developer Edition to Chrome and it work. Thanks